# Populating a Django formset using a left join

Tags: django, formset

I have the following models: Topic, UserProfile, UserSubscribedToTopic

The last of these looks like this:

```
class UserSubscribedToTopic(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
    user_profile = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile)
    start_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
```

I want to show a list of topics to the user, with a checkbox by each. If the user checks a checkbox then I'll use JavaScript to show the 'start date' text field (so for the purposes of this question I just need to show a text field next to the checkbox). If the user has already saved their selection and is revisiting the page I want to populate the form accordingly when it is first rendered.

I've attempted to do this using formsets:

```
class SubscribeToTopicForm(ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = UserSubscribedToTopic
    fields = ('topic','start_date')
    widgets = {'topic': CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'topic-checkbox'}),
               'start_date': TextInput(attrs={'class': 'date','placeholder': 'Start date'})}

SubscribeToTopicFormSetBase = modelformset_factory(
    UserSubscribedToTopic,
    form=SubscribeToTopicForm,
    extra = 0)

class SubscribeToTopicFormSet(SubscribeToTopicFormSetBase):
def add_fields(self, form, index):
    super(SubscribeToTopicFormSet, self).add_fields(form, index)
```

I almost get what I want if I add the following to my view:

```
topics_formset = SubscribeToTopicFormSet(queryset=UserSubscribedToTopic.objects.filter(user_profile=user.get_profile()))
```

However, obviously this will only show the topics to which the user has already subscribed. To show all the topics I really need to do is a LEFT JOIN on the Topic table. I can't see how to do this in Django without resorting to raw.

My questions:

- Am I right in thinking it is not possible to specify a queryset for
  the formset that is generated from a left join?
- Would it be better to
  give up on ModelForm and use a formset that I populate manually?
- Any better approaches?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up separating out the checkboxes from the date fields, so I could use a forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField in a Form and a manually-created formset to deal with the date fields.

Here's the code:

Forms:

```
class SubscribedToTopicForm(ModelForm):
    subscribed_to_topic = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(required=False,queryset=Topic.available_topics, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(attrs={'class': 'topic-checkbox'}))
    class Meta:
    model = UserProfile
    fields = ("subscribed_to_topic",)

    def get_checked_topics(self):
        return self.cleaned_data['subscribed_to_topic']

class StartDateForm(forms.Form):
    topic_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput,required=False)
    start_date = forms.DateField(required=False,label='')

StartDateFormSetBase = formset_factory(form=StartDateForm,extra = 0)

class StartDateFormSet(StartDateFormSetBase):
    def get_start_date(self, topic_id):
        for i in range(0, self.total_form_count()):
            form = self.forms[i]
            form_topic_id=long(form.cleaned_data['topic_id'])
            if topic_id == form_topic_id:
                return form.cleaned_data['start_date']
        return ''
```

View:

GET:

```
topics_form = SubscribedToTopicForm()
subscribed_to_topic=None
if request.user.is_authenticated():
    subscribed_to_topics = SubscribedToTopic.objects.filter(user_profile=request.user.get_profile())
initial_data = []
for topic in Topic.available_topics.all():
    start_date=''
    if subscribed_to_topics:
        for subscribed_to_topic in subscribed_to_topics:
            if subscribed_to_topic.topic.id==topic.id:
                start_date=subscribed_to_topic.start_date
    initial_data.append({'topic_id':topic.id, 'start_date': start_date})
start_date_formset = StartDateFormSet(initial=initial_data)
```

POST:

```
start_date_formset = StartDateFormSet(request.POST)
topics_form = SubscribedToTopicForm(request.POST)
start_date_formset.is_valid()
topics_form.is_valid()
for topic in topics_form.get_checked_topics():
    start_date = start_date_formset.get_start_date(topic.id)
    subscribed_to_topic = SubscribedToTopic()
    subscribed_to_topic.topic=topic
    subscribed_to_topic.start_date=start_date
    subscribed_to_topic.save()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create the form on the `Topic` model, then use the `user_set` manager to see if the current user has subscribed to the topic.

Once the form is submitted, if any fields are checked, you can then create individual `UserSubscribedToTopic` objects in your view.